# How to define django app specific exception handler

Tags: django, exception

For my django app I am creating a custom exception handler as defined in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

Is there a way to define REST_FRAMEWORK variable in some app specific settings file instead of global settings.py

Comment: Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Share django server with multiple apps. Do not want to override exception response for other apps.

Comment: Makes sense indeed. First you should make sure (if you didn't already) that DRF's custom exception handlers apply to _all_ views or only DRF APIViews. If that's the case, the DRF's custom exception handler will get the view object in which the exception occured, so you can test by yourself whether it was from an APIView and ignore it if not.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no app specific exception handling, you can get things like view, request etc.. through custom exception handler and handle it with if-else block

> The context argument is not used by the default handler, but can be useful if the exception handler needs further information such as
>   the view currently being handled, which can be accessed as
>   **`context['view']`**.